# SQL Query repetitive `AND` query, how do I avoid it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query here:

```
DECLARE @date Date;

SET @date = '2020-11-24';

SELECT p.description AS ProductDescription, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%400' THEN requiredQty * 10
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%400OL' THEN requiredQty * 10
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%396' THEN requiredQty * 6
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%396OL' THEN requiredQty * 6
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%101' THEN requiredQty * 1
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%101OL' THEN requiredQty * 1
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%393OL' THEN requiredQty * 3
        ELSE 0 END) AS RequiredQty,
    '1kg' AS PackSize
FROM SalesOrderLine sol JOIN 
    SalesOrder so
    ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id JOIN
    Product p 
    ON sol.productID = p.id
WHERE 
    p.code like '%396' AND
    so.dueDate = @date
    OR
    p.code like '%396OL' AND
    so.dueDate = @date
    OR
    p.code like '%400' AND
    so.dueDate = @date
    OR
    p.code like '%400OL' AND
    so.dueDate = @date
    OR
    p.code like '%101' AND
    so.dueDate = @date
    OR
    p.code like '%101OL' AND
    so.dueDate = @date
    OR
    p.code like '%393OL' AND
    so.dueDate = @date
GROUP BY p.description;
```

**Question**

I use this `AND so.dueDate = @date` multiple times to get accurate data. Without it, I will get data from years ago.

Maybe I have this query very long winded? Is there a way to avoid repeating myself with the same query over and over again?

Comment: parentheses - `(A OR B OR C) AND D` - just as with many languages, let's you control how AND and OR operators are combined

Comment: Start with putting all your magic numbers in a table. Hard-coding them is causing you problems like this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Great tip!

Comment: You could create a temp table with your options in and use 'in #temptable'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the query in several ways:

```
SELECT p.description AS ProductDescription, 
       SUM(requiredQty * v.factor) as RequiredQty,
       '1kg' AS PackSize
FROM SalesOrderLine sol JOIN 
     SalesOrder so
     ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id JOIN
     Product p 
     ON sol.productID = p.id JOIN
     (VALUES ('%400', 10), ('%400L', 10),
             ('%396', 6), ('%396L', 6),
             ('%101', 1), ('%101L', 1),
             ('%393OL', 3)
     ) v(pattern, factor)
     ON p.code LIKE v.pattern
WHERE so.dueDate = @date
GROUP BY p.description;
```

The `JOIN` takes care of the filtering.

Note:  Because of the multiple uses of `LIKE` in your and the fact that at most one row matches, I think the about `JOIN` will not be particularly expensive.  But you can replace the logic with a `CASE` expression using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT p.description AS ProductDescription, 
       SUM(requiredQty * v.factor) as RequiredQty,
       '1kg' AS PackSize
FROM SalesOrderLine sol JOIN 
     SalesOrder so
     ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id JOIN
     Product p 
     ON sol.productID = p.id CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN p.code LIKE '%400' THEN 10
                   WHEN p.code LIKE '%400OL' THEN 10
                   WHEN p.code LIKE '%396' THEN 6
                   WHEN p.code LIKE '%396OL' THEN 6
                   WHEN p.code LIKE '%101' THEN 1
                   WHEN p.code LIKE '%101OL' THEN 1
                   WHEN p.code LIKE '%393OL' THEN 3
              END)
     ) v(factor)
WHERE so.dueDate = @date AND
      f.factor IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.description;
```

Answer (score -1):

As was mentioned in the comments, you just need to properly encapsulate your filtering criteria so that the relevant conditions are evaluated once and combined appropriately:

```
DECLARE @date Date;

SET @date = '2020-11-24';

SELECT p.description AS ProductDescription, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%400' THEN requiredQty * 10
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%400OL' THEN requiredQty * 10
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%396' THEN requiredQty * 6
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%396OL' THEN requiredQty * 6
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%101' THEN requiredQty * 1
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%101OL' THEN requiredQty * 1
            WHEN p.code LIKE '%393OL' THEN requiredQty * 3
        ELSE 0
        END) AS RequiredQty,
    '1kg' AS PackSize
FROM SalesOrderLine sol
    JOIN SalesOrder so
        ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id
    JOIN Product p 
        ON sol.productID = p.id
WHERE (p.code like '%396'
       OR p.code like '%396OL'
       OR p.code like '%400'
       OR p.code like '%400OL'
       OR p.code like '%101'
       OR p.code like '%101OL'
       OR p.code like '%393OL'
      )
   AND so.dueDate = @date
GROUP BY p.description;
```

---

From this query, you may also find you get some performance improvements by storing and indexing a reversed version of your `code` values, so you aren't scanning the whole table due to your `like '%val'` criteria.

To keep your code readable, you could apply your filters like this:

```
WHERE (p.codeReverse like reverse('396') + '%'
      etc
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is okay. But the second part with the `reverse` code will not work. Please check closely what you have written, and explain again.

Comment: @SQLPolice Do please add some detail as to why you think that won't work, [as I am pretty sure it will](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=37a252663e1b603b30d8ed38018dd161).

Comment: In your answer, suddenly a field  "codeReverse" is popping up. You don't explain where it is coming from and what it contains.

Comment: @SQLPolice Yes, the field that I suggested could be created to aid in doing these searches: *"you may also find you get some performance improvements **by storing and indexing a reversed version of your code values**"*